# No default constructor exists for a class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, definition

I get these errors when I run the program:

> no default constructor exists for class "DynamicArray"
>
> 'DynamicArray':no appropiate default constructor available.

Could you help me out?

Repository.h

```
class Repository {

private:
    DynamicArray Repository_Dogs;

public:
    Repository(int capacity , int Size_Dogs_List);

};
```

```
Dog::Dog(char* name, char* breed, char* birth_date, char* vaccinations_counter, char* photograph)
{
    strcpy(this->Name, name);
    strcpy(this->Breed, breed);
    strcpy(this->Birth_Date, birth_date);
    strcpy(this->Vaccinations_Counter, vaccinations_counter);
    strcpy(this->Photograph, photograph);
}
```

Repository.cpp

```
Repository::Repository(int capacity , int size_Dogs_List)
{
    DynamicArray newDynamicArray =  DynamicArray(capacity,size_Dogs_List);
    this->Repository_Dogs = newDynamicArray;


}
```

DynamicArray.cpp

```
DynamicArray::DynamicArray(int capacity, int size_Dogs_List)
{
    this->Capacity_List = capacity;
    this->Size_Dogs_List = size_Dogs_List;
    this->Dogs_List = (Dog*)malloc(this->Capacity_List * sizeof(Dog));
}
```

DynamicArray.h(constructor)

```
public:

    DynamicArray(int capacity, int Size_Dogs_List);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the constructor like

```
Repository::Repository(int capacity , int size_Dogs_List) 
    : Repository_Dogs( capacity, size_Dogs_List )
{
}
```

And instead of the C function malloc use the operator new.

Comment: new Dog[100] doesn't work , how should I allocate memory ?

Comment: @VladGhetina I can not answer because I have no enough information for example why it is not work. Does the class Dog have the default constructor?

Comment: @VladGhetina The class Dog has no default constructor. You could use the placement new operator but I think you do not know it yet..